# Adding a new element to a nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I'm trying to add a new message (with key "3") to the nested "messages" document but $addToSet or $push won't work. Is it possible to push a new message element to such a structure? In the beginning the messages property was an array but my mongodb provider converts arrays into such structures. Just for your information: I'm accessing the mongodb via node.js and mongojs but a native mongodb solution would be perfect too.

```
{
    "messages" : 
    {
        "0" : 
        {
            "foo": "bar0"  
        },
        "1" : 
        {
            "foo": "bar1"  
        },
        "2" : 
        {
            "foo": "bar2"   
        },
    },
    "name" : "MyName"   
}
```

Comment: `$addToSet` and `$push` will only work with arrays (enclosed within []).  In your document, `messages` is an object rather than an array.  So, you'll have to use the `update` statement: `db.collection.update({}, {$set:{"messages.3":{"foo":"bar3"}}})`

Comment: I thought of something like that but then I have to get the count of the messages document first, right?

Comment: Which is why you should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: Indeed buuuuut when I add the document via the editor of my provider then it converts the array into such a document :/

Comment: Hm I am using the one from MongoSoup. It is a german mongodb provider.

Comment: If you are storing as an array, might be there is an issue with the editor displaying it. You should store it as an array, as you were, and $push, $addToSet would definitely work. Show how you used them.

Comment: var message = { "foo": "bar3" };
mongodb.collection.update({ _id:mongojs.ObjectId(objectId) }, { $push: { messages: message }}, callback);
Note: this is mongojs notation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the editor of MongoSoup automatically transforms arrays into a collection of documents. When I create the array via command line or my node.js application then everything is like I've expected it.

Thank you anyway ... my bad!

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you just want to add a subdocument, so simply `$set`ting the document will work:

```
db.bar.update({_id : ObjectId("542194f8b32cda36885e1d9e") }, 
              {$set : {"messages.3" : {"foo" : "bar3"}}})
```

You would need to substitute an appropriate match criteria rather than the _id I used of course based on what your real documents look like.  Full procedure for adding/updating your sample document as follows:

```
> foo = {
    "messages" : {
        "0" : {
            "foo" : "bar0"
        },
        "1" : {
            "foo" : "bar1"
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : "bar2"
        }
    },
    "name" : "MyName"
}

> db.bar.insert(foo)
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.bar.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542194f8b32cda36885e1d9e"),
    "messages" : {
        "0" : {
            "foo" : "bar0"
        },
        "1" : {
            "foo" : "bar1"
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : "bar2"
        }
    },
    "name" : "MyName"
}

> db.bar.update({_id : ObjectId("542194f8b32cda36885e1d9e") }, {$set : {"messages.3" : {"foo" : "bar3"}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.bar.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("542194f8b32cda36885e1d9e"),
    "messages" : {
        "0" : {
            "foo" : "bar0"
        },
        "1" : {
            "foo" : "bar1"
        },
        "2" : {
            "foo" : "bar2"
        },
        "3" : {
            "foo" : "bar3"
        }
    },
    "name" : "MyName"
}
```

The obvious limitation is that this would overwrite any existing `messages.3` field if it already exists, so you will need to be careful and you need to keep track of the latest message in the field also.

Comment: The OP does not store the document in such a way. Its stored as  an array.

Comment: That's actually not what the question says, in fact the title explicitly says that it is a nested doc and not an array, which is why the $push operator will not work

Comment: I guess then, the title is misleading, please read the description and the comments.

Comment: "In the beginning the messages property was an array but my mongodb provider converts arrays into such structures", "Indeed buuuuut when I add the document via the editor of my provider then it converts the array into such a document :/", and the title seem to be confusing. I don't think the answer is correct in this context.

Comment: Right, so the document is not an array, it *is* a nested document, and I have used the document example given.  If what you are saying is correct, then every single part of the question is incorrect - title, description and sample document.  I have answered the question as asked, you appear to want me to answer something that was never actually asked that you are inferring from.......nowhere - that makes no sense to me

Comment: I checked the database via command line and mongojs and when I do a "find" query on the messages array (supposed to be an array) then I'll get message documents and no array ... seems to me that it is really stored as a collection of documents. Maybe this is why: https://www.mongosoup.de/blog-entry/Storing-Large-Lists-In-MongoDB.html